# register form not adding data to realtime database of firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

So I don't understand firebase and I was wondering why this simple register form is not sending the data to my realtime database in firebase.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="mainForm" class="w-25 m-4">
        <h2 class="mb-3">Register User</h2>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
            <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordInput" placeholder="Password">
            <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usernameInput" placeholder="Username">
            <label for="usernameInput">Username</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;">Create New User</button>
        <a href="login.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary me-2"  style="float: right;">Log Into Existing Account</button></a>
        
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="module">
        import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-analytics.js";
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-app.js";
        import { getDatabase, set,ref } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-database.js";
        import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-auth.js";
      
        const firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "AIzaSyCldJtrt23-mz3CIubgwGc02tzJxfRoHa8",
          authDomain: "fitforged-b9d11.firebaseapp.com",
          projectId: "fitforged-b9d11",
          storageBucket: "fitforged-b9d11.appspot.com",
          messagingSenderId: "618367077709",
          appId: "1:618367077709:web:5a5517cab12a9271963b04",
          measurementId: "G-ZY3NK4ZT38"
        };
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
        const db = getDatabase(app);
        const auth = getAuth(app);

        let emailInput=document.getElementById('emailInput');
        let passwordInput=document.getElementById('passwordInput');
        let usernameInput=document.getElementById('usernameInput');
        let mainForm=document.getElementById('mainForm');

        let RegisterUser = evt =>{
            evt.preventDefault();
            createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, emailInput.value,passwordInput.value)
            .then((credentials)=>{
                const user = credentials.user;
                set(ref(db,'users/'+user.uid),{
                    username: usernameInput.value,
                    email: emailInput.value,
                })
                console.log(credentials);
                window.location.href='home.html';
                alert("successfully created user");
            })
            .catch((error)=>{
                alert(error.message);
                console.log(error.message);
            })    
        }
        mainForm.addEventListener('submit',RegisterUser);

      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried different versions of firebase and changed the read and write properties of the realtime database to true as well. I also tried to change the database itself and make a new one and that didn't work too

Answer (score 0):

Writing to the Firebase Realtime Database is an asynchronous operation, because it happens on a server. Your code sets `window.location.href='home.html';` before the call to the database has completed, navigating to a new page immediately, and aborting the database write in the process.

Just like the code you uses `then()` to wait for `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, you need to use `then()` too to wait for the `set` call to complete.

```js
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, emailInput.value,passwordInput.value)
.then((credentials)=>{
    const user = credentials.user;
    set(ref(db,'users/'+user.uid),{
        username: usernameInput.value,
        email: emailInput.value,
    }).then(() => {
        console.log(credentials);
        window.location.href='home.html';
    });
})
```